# Regex Help for a Command

Tags: java, regex, parsing, command

I need to parse this Command:

```
direct print conference <style>:<First Name Last Name>,<First Name Last Name>,<First Name Last Name>,<title>,<conference series name>,<location>,<year>
```

A Example Command would be:

> direct print conference ieee:Sergey Brin,Lawrence Page,,The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine,WWW,Brisbane Australia,1998

My Main Problem is (First Name Last Name) can be empty, but how do I do that with Regex?

For The (First Name Last Name) i always do ([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) but How do I definiate Empty Possible Places with Regex?

```
direct print conference ([a-zA-Z]+):([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+),([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+),([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+),([^,]+),([a-zA-Z]+),([a-zA-Z ]+),([0-9]+)
```

That is my Regex for if the names are not empty but How i can include Empty Characters to my Regex like:

```
([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+) OR EMPTY ?
```

I Hope you can Help me

Comment: Try `*` instead of `+` - it means "zero or more occurrences of ..." instead of "one or more occurrences of ...".  Also, you could learn how to use `?` which kind of means "maybe".

Comment: Wrap with optional non-capturing groups: `([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+)` -> `(?:([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+))?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That would make  it difficult to know which match corresponded to which field.

Comment: @David It is not difficult as the number of capturing groups sets the number of groups in each match.

Answer (score 1):

Since your input is basicaly a CSV with a special start, you don't need regex here, just `String.split()`:

```
String input = "direct print conference ieee:Sergey Brin,Lawrence Page,,The Anatomy of a Large-Scale Hypertextual Web Search Engine,WWW,Brisbane Australia,1998";
String[] parts = input.split(":");

String[] values = parts[1].split(",");

for(int i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

See it [live](https://ideone.com/DJ5WNK)

Comment: .. and where `First Name Last Name` count is variable, it is better use array items from last item to the first one (year,...) @Jone Daniel